# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs

Tengo este código cuando aplico el useCallBack(), me da ese warning como lo puedo solucionar?

```
const onCompleteStep = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(mantenimientoTienda.setIsComplete(true));
    onContinue();
};
```

Comment: Quita los 2 ; y solo pon una , en **(true));**

Comment: Gracias Josue, ya lo intenté y no funcionó, el warning me lo tira al cerrar el bracket en la última linea  };

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un parentesis de cierre al final

```
const onCompleteStep = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(mantenimientoTienda.setIsComplete(true));
    onContinue();
})
```

Comment: Ahora recibo esto: 70:28  warning  React Hook useCallback does nothing when called with only one argument. Did you forget to pass an array of dependencies?  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  70:28  error    'useCallback' is not defined

Comment: Para ser más preciso, tenía este código:

Comment: const onCompleteStep = () => {
        dispatch(vsWarrantyMaintenanceActions.setIsComplete(true));
        onContinue();
    };

Comment: tu pregunta se resuelve arreglando la sintaxis, ahora tienes un error diferente, el cual tiene que ver con los hooks y es otro problema aparte.

Comment: Y me da este warning:  The 'onCompleteStep' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 80) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the definition of 'onCompleteStep' in its own useCallback() Hook

Comment: NO se si estoy utilizando mal el useCallBack()